# HTML Select box display question

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Is there anyway I can control the way the select box displays. Currently it is showing as below, here I want see select box downwards. That is after text "Test:" I want to see "Select" and the entire box should go down. Is it possible?

[image]

And here is my code for this:

```
Test: <select multiple="multiple" size="5">
        <option value="none" selected >Select</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="audi">Honda</option>
        <option value="audi">Toyota</option>
        <option value="audi">BMW</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I have tested all your answers and all works! For my case @moses answer looks right fit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Town's;

Way 1:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td valign="top">Test: </td>
  <td valign="top">Select box here</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Way 2:

```
<div style="float: left;">Text: </div>
<div style="float: left;">Select box here</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you place all your content within a `div` and the 'Test:' text within a `span`, you can use CSS's `vertical-align: top` to align the `span` to the top of its parent, like so:

```
<div>
    <span style="vertical-align: top;">Test:</span>
    <select multiple="multiple" size="5">
        <option value="none" selected >Select</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="honda">Honda</option>
        <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
        <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly ...

You can just add a `<div>` tag around the select box.

```
<div>
<select>...</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Just putting it in a div does not correct the alignment of the label. You still need to use styles to correct this.

Comment: @john3laze the OP said nothing about alignment. He just said "go down." Am I supposed to be able to read his mind now? :)

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want is to add a "vertical-align:top;" to your select and text container.  That should fix it for you.

Comment: Like this; Test: <select multiple="multiple" size="5" style="vertical-align: top;">. Nope. That shouldn't fix it for him.

Comment: True, I mean to say both as other people have mentioned since I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/bobkruithof/jSB5F/

Answer (score 0):

Create a container around the two objects (text and selectbox), and separate the objects by giving them their own div, and apply vertical-align, and float:left property for the text div.

```
<div>
    <div style="vertical-align:top; float:left;">
        Test:
    </div>
    <div>
    <select multiple="multiple" size="5" style="vertical-align:text-bottom;">
        <option value="none" selected >Select</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="audi">Honda</option>
        <option value="audi">Toyota</option>
        <option value="audi">BMW</option>
      </select>
      </div>
</div>
```